Compile Qt 5.12 with Visual Studio 2022
On the way to build Qt from source, I got the qt-everywhere-src-5.12.11.zip. My goal is to build it with Visual Studio 2022 to include it on the Qt Creator Kits, since I need to change to VS 2022.
On my computer I have W10 22H2, so as here is specified it should work, I guess.
When I follow the build steps for Qt, I execute first at all the little script just adapted for the VS 2022:
REM Set up \Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, where <arch> is \c amd64, \c x86, etc.
CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
SET _ROOT=C:\Qt\Qt5.12.11
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\Tools\QtCreator\bin;%PATH%
REM Uncomment the below line when using a git checkout of the source repository
REM SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtrepotools\bin;%PATH%
SET _ROOT=

After executing that script, I receive this:
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.11.2
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

So, next step is execute the configure, where I obtain:
configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -opensource -prefix C:\Qt\Qt5.12.11\5.12.11\msvc2022_64

So, I get the output from configure (not gonna display all, but the relevant parts), where it is shown the compiler and c++ version:
Configure summary:

Build type: win32-msvc (x86_64, CPU features: sse sse2)
Compiler: msvc 194033811
Configuration: sse2 aesni sse3 ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 avx avx2 avx512f avx512bw avx512cd avx512dq avx512er avx512ifma avx512pf avx512vbmi avx512vl compile_examples f16c largefile precompile_header rdrnd shani x86SimdAlways shared debug_and_release release debug build_all c++11 c++14 c++1z concurrent dbus no-pkg-config release_tools stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... debug and release; default link: debug; optimized tools
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C89
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++1z
  Using gold linker ...................... no
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE .................................. SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2
    AVX .................................. AVX AVX2
    AVX512 ............................... F ER CD PF DQ BW VL IFMA VBMI
    Other x86 ............................ AES F16C RDRAND SHA
  Build parts ............................ libs tools
  App store compliance ................... no

From here I guess the compiler that will be used should be Visual Studio 2022, as can be see here
Now I add it to the Qt Versions on the Qt Creator, but on the details I get:

And I cannot create a new Kit which uses the C++ Compiler 17.7 (this is Visual Studio 2022) with this Qt Version, as it complains:

I updated VS 2022 to the last version recently, but right now I'm out of ideas.
I appreciate any help.

Obviously the used Qt Creator version doesn't known about VS2022 yet? Notice how it completely miss-classified the compiler version as belonging to VS2005 instead?
You got to keep your Qt Creator version up to date, don't be a fool a think if would continue to work just because you had originally installed it together with the Qt 5.12.

Btw.: It's not as if you actually had any good reason to recompile Qt in the first place, MSVC2015 to MSVC2022 had so far been ABI-compatible all the way. Even if your main code base is going up to VS2022 / VC++ 17.x, you can still use all libraries pre-compiled with VC++ 14.x and newer.
